# React.js state filtering error. ( Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, array-filter

React state filter error. Hello there. I am working on an API implementation in React. I get movie information through an API and assign that information to the state. The application also has an item search module. And it shows the items in the state according to the information that the user writes. I am doing this module with the following filtering, but unfortunately I am getting an error.
here is my code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
state = {
    movies: [],
    searchQueryState: ""
}
async componentDidMount(){
    const response = await axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/list/${7101545}?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&language=en-US`);
    const data =  response.data.items;
    console.log(data)
    this.setState({movies: data})        
}
deleteMovie = async (movie) => {
    axios.post(`
    https://api.themoviedb.org/3/list/7101545/remove_item?media_id=${movie.id}&session_id=${process.env.REACT_APP_SESSION_ID}&api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}
    `);
    const newMovieList = this.state.movies.filter(
        m => m.id !== movie.id
    )
    this.setState(state => (
        {
            movies: newMovieList
        }
    ))
}
searchQuery = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        searchQueryState: event.target.value
    })
}
render() {
    let filteredMovies = this.state.movies.filter(
        movie => {
            console.log(movie)
            return movie.original_title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.searchQueryState.toLowerCase()) !== -1
        }
    )
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12">
                    <SearchBar
                        searchMovieProp={this.searchQuery}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="container">
                <MovieList
                    movies={filteredMovies}
                    deleteMovieProps={this.deleteMovie}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is the part where I got the error:

```
 let filteredMovies = this.state.movies.filter(
        movie => {
            console.log(movie)
            return movie.original_title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.searchQueryState.toLowerCase()) !== -1
        }
    )
```

*Here is my error: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined (anonymous function) C:/Users/melak/Desktop/arin-react/my-movies-1/src/components/App.js:65 62 | const filteredMovies = this.state.movies.filter( 63 | movie => { 64 | console.log(movie)*

Comment: Does the objects printed by the `console.log` contains a property `original_title`? If not, this is the problem.

Comment: yes, it contains.

Comment: Then the problem is with the state `searchQueryState`. Double check the state update, verify if it is being set when you type

Comment: I checked it, it works fine. I think the problem is after the "return" part.

Comment: The error says `Cannot ready property "toLowerCase" of undefined`. So, the `searchQueryState`is undefined or the property `original_title`of the movies is undefined. Check, within the filter, if the `searchQueryState` isn't undefined. Also, Instead of using `indexOf`, I suggest you to use the `includes`, that returns a boolean if the string is present within the `original_title`

Comment: i tried "contains" method but same thing

Comment: Sorry, it should be `includes`, not `contains`. By the way, this won't solve the problem, it's just an improvement. Did you tried to console.log the `searchQueryState`within the filter? If so, is it undefined or not?

Comment: I got the problem! In the array returning from API, some movie names are returning as undefined.